# Finding out if my system is being used as a bot by looking at ifconfig?

Tags: security, router, ifconfig

Recently, I have often been suspicious that my router (a linux box) might have been used as a bot for spam blowout or something of that quality because I may have misconfigured my iptables rules by accident. (I believe those are fixed now.)

While looking at the box and trying to find out what may have gone wrong, I once noticed that the data for the amount of received and transmitted packets on the internal (eth0) and external (eth1, ppp0) interfaces sometimes had a severe mismatch. The router itself shouldn't be creating any significant traffic to the outside unless I tell it to (updates using apt-get and the like), and the slightly different numbers on the internal (eth0) interface are caused by logging in via ssh. However, there should never be huge numbers on the external interface (and not on the internal) under my circumstances, right? So here is my question:

Can I tell if my router is being used as a bot by looking at the output of ifconfig? Should the numbers (at least roughly) match like shown here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume these counters (`eth0`, `eth1`) refer to layer 2 data. Thus the `eth1` traffic would be the `ppp0` traffic plus the PPPoE overhead.

Furthermore Ethernet transfer has collisions (as shown in your output), virtual interface traffic doesn't.

Another source for traffic increase is the MSS handling (for TCP). I.e. the router sends ICMP packets which have not been sent by the network behind it.

If your system had been abused (for spam) then the differences would be huge (if the counters have not been tampered with).

Comment: "then the differences would be huge..." They were huge - as in: Several GB as opposed to some hundred MB of expected (own) traffic. Glad it's fixed now after I caught up on how iptables works. Also, thanks for filling me in on the details.